# Become a Cloud Security analyst

Tags: appsec, cloud-computing

What learning path would you recommend for someone interesting in focussing on the Cloud Security side and considering remote work in the future?

Many thanks

Comment: That's a really broad question. What layer of cloud?

Answer (score 0):

To become a cloud security analyst, you should have a good understanding of cloud computing architectures and approaches and a firm understanding of the threat models, vulnerabilities, standards, solutions and services offered by various vendors. I have compiled a list of essential concepts related to cloud security in my [slideshare](https://www2.slideshare.net/gokulalex/cloud-security-engineering-tools-and-techniques) presentation. Hope this would be a useful reference material.